# What kind of connection exists between innerRadiusRatio and thicknessRatio from GradientDrawable class?

Tags: android, math, view, drawable

Let's supposed we've got a ring with inner radius R2 and outer radius R1. According documentation:
`Inner radius of the ring expressed as a ratio of the ring's width.For instance, if innerRadiusRatio=9, then the inner radius equals the ring's width divided by 9` 
As I understand this means that `innerRadiusRatio = 2*R1 / R2`.

About thicknessRatio there is that:
`Thickness of the ring expressed as a ratio of the ring's width. For instance, if thicknessRatio=3, then the thickness equals the ring's width divided by 3`. So `thicknessRatio = 2*R1 / (R1 - R2)`.

From this two equationі we can get this one: `thicknessRatio*(1-2/innerRadiusRatio)=2` which means that there is a connection between thicknessRatio and innerRadiusRatio. But there is nothing about this connection in [GradientDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html) class documentation. And it doesn't seem that there is any connections between them as I can set thicknessRatio and innerRadiusRatio which doesn't satisfying last equation.

So tell me please where I'm wrong in my consideration or what are this parameters really responsible for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ratios are a comparison of two numbers, so the above two equations can be rewritten as

Ratio1 = InnerRadius **:** Ring Width (where Ratio1 = InnerRadiusRatio)

Ratio2 = Thickness **:** Ring Width (where Ratio2 = ThicknessRatio)

Which means...

Ring Width = Ratio1 **x** Inner Radius = Ratio2 **x** Thickness

The "**2**" appeared since you added it into your equation. The only common denominator in all equation is "Ring Width". Trying it out with real numbers helps too.

Comment: This equation : Ratio1 x Inner Radius = Ratio2 x Thickness means that there is connection between InnerRadiusRatio and ThicknessRatio. But we can set both this values independently and they are both applying well even when they don't satisfying equation.

Comment: Eg: when using <shape android:shape="ring"........</shape>, you can either set android:InnerRadius= or android:InnerRadiusRatio=, if both are set, ratios are ignored. With Ratios, use the <size android:width...> to calculate the InnerRadius and Thickness.

Comment: Forgot to add: Setting one ratio won't affect the other ratio nor the width. Example: Width=48dip; Ratio1=3 => InnerRadius=48/3=16; Ratio2=8 ==> Thickness=48/8=6. So if you set Thickness=5 in your code, it will simply override (ignore) Ratio2.

Answer (score 52):

I know this is pretty late, but it may help others looking for this.

In the documentation it says:

> Inner radius of the ring expressed as a ratio of **the ring's width**.

The ring's width is not the Radius of the ring, it is the width of the view containing the ring. I draw this for an easier explanation:

[image]

That's the scheme of a view with a ring inside. The letters mean:

- W: Width
- P: Padding
- Th: Thickness
- Ir: Inner Radius.

And I will add:

- R: Radius.
- IRR: InnerRadiusRatio.
- THR: ThicknesRatio.

The documentation actually describes the following relationship:

- Ir = W/IRR
- Th = W/THR

So you can actually calculate the Radius.

- R = Ir + Th = W (1/IRR + 1/THR).

You can prove this by creating a view with a Ring that has:

```
InnerRadiusRatio="4"
ThicknessRatio="4".
```

This will create a ring that has exactly the same width as the view.

**Note:** All of the previous formulas are calculated with **no padding**. If there is padding on the View, you should replace every W with (W - P).

Comment: **The ring's width is not the Radius of the ring, it is the width of the view containing the ring.** +1

Comment: Oh, yes, great answer! Thanks!

Comment: very well explained. better than the above 2 answers