# Scale drawable circle according to screen size

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, drawable, shapes

Its been a while I am stuck with this. I am a newbie android developer.

I have a drawable circle.

**circular_shape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:useLevel="false"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="0.8dp">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>
</shape>
```

now i want to use this circle in my activity layout in such a way that it covers the whole screen. That is, the width of the screen should be equal to Diameter of the circle.
Note that I have not set the radius of the circle.

**example_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/exampleLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.anil.raceorganizer.ExampleActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/race_field"
        android:src="@drawable/circular_shape"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        ></ImageView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Note that I have tried to put padding and margin as 0, but it didn't work.
I also tried setting the size of the ImageView through code, but it only changed the size of the ImageView as a whole and not circle alone.

This is what I get with this code.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to use Canvas to draw image than xml, I can give and example

Comment: If you want I can show you how to draw with a compass

Comment: @Stallion - please do show

Comment: @lelloman - please do show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="0.8dp"
    android:useLevel="false"
    android:innerRadiusRatio="2.1">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />
</shape>
```

Comment: i don't think innerradiusratio has anything to do with screen size

Comment: You can change screen size to test my code. I assure that it will work correctly. :)).<br> By default, innerRadiusRatio = 1, it means your circle = 1/2 your width.

Comment: I am afraid I can't change size of my clients mobile screens to match your value _2.1_!! This is for a live project!

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29151532/3929188) says InnerRadiusRatio = RingWidth/Radius. Where RingWidth is the width of the view. So yes. Your answer is indeed correct and was useful to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using Canvas, we can draw shapes matching the screen width.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    int width = display.getWidth();
    int height = display.getHeight();

    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);

    Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp);

    RectF rect = new RectF(0,0,width,width);
    drawCircle(rect, c, width, height);

}

private void drawCircle(RectF rect, Canvas c, int width, int height) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setARGB(255, 255 , 10, 21);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(8);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.BUTT);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        int radius;
        if(width < height)
            radius = width/2;
        else 
            radius = height/2;

        radius-= 4;
        c.drawCircle(width/2, height/2, radius, paint);
    }
```

Not sure if it might help you. If its not , let me know. I will prefer deleting than getting downvotes!

Comment: ok I don't like your solution, you might do the same thing extending a Drawable and imho it would look better...but I'm not brave enough to downvote Rambo

Comment: @lelloman before answering I enquired if I could put this as an answer. According to anil_pulikoden's reply only I posted.

Comment: It works. But I dont think i need a canvas for my activity. gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Try this
You can use this tag in drawable

```
android:innerRadius="150dp"
```

change the radius accordingly

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

use the width from the above

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:useLevel="false"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:innerRadius="150dp"
        android:thickness="0.8dp">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>
    </shape>
```

Comment: but i want it to be the size of the screen. Not 150dp. Do you know how to set this radius dynamically?

Comment: How to set the radius? that was my question1

Answer (score 0):

Use this kind of approach to get ring like structure.

Use size tag to preserve 1:1 aspect ratio

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval" >

<size android:width="50dp"
 android:height="50dp"/>

<stroke android:color="#000" android:width="0.1dp"/>

</shape>
```

Comment: I put this code. But there is no change in circle. My question was how to change the circle diameter to width of the screen. any ideas?